# Tab width is resized when tab text changes

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, ellipsis

Given tabs in an ActionBAr with custom layouts for displaying 2 texts like this one:

[image]

And the custom layout defined as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/LightBlue"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textColor="@color/Yellow"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I change text1 to a longer string (in this example the longer string is "TEMPORARYTEMPORARY") 2 things happen:

1. The tab width is expanded, pushing the other tabs off screen, though it seems to be there is a max tab width since the longer string is clipped.
2. Even though the longer string is clipped, the ellipsize attribute has no effect, no marquee (tried ellipsize "end" and it also has no effect)

[image]

I want the tabs to remain the same size, spanning the screen width, not beyond that. And in any case I want the ellipsize attribute to take effect on text1.

**UPDATE**
 The epllipsize works if instead of

```
android:maxlines="1"
```

I use

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Still the tab width is widened to some maximum pushing the rightmost one a little off screen,

Comment: Consider setting following attributes for your TextView

android:minWidth or minEms
android:maxWidth or minMax

Comment: @ilomambo r u using shrelockActionBar library ?

Comment: @Anirudh All those attributes seem to expect an absolute size, which I don't know.

Comment: @Pratik No sherlockActionBar, regular ActionBar

Comment: @Anirudh I don't think you are thinking through your own answers. I'll let you find what is wrong with your last suggestion by your own. If you still think it works, please post a proper answer with some snippet of working code.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to keep the tabs bounded to the screen width. Plus the ellipsize solution I posted before in the question itself, it solves my problem.
To summarize:

Ellipsize will work if the `singleline` attribute is set on the TextView XML

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

The tabs are automatically resized according to the widest of them and this may cause the tabs to become "scrollable" and slide off screen. To prevent that I used:

```
    tv.setMaxWidth(screenwidth/3-70);
```

The maxwidth will keep the 3 tabs the same width and prevent them sliding away.
The `-70` is temporary until I found out where I can get the tab's padding from.

**EDIT**
Final code with actual padding taken from the tab itself

```
private void setTabsMaxWidth() {
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    final View tabView = actionBar.getTabAt(0).getCustomView();
    final View tabContainerView = (View) tabView.getParent();
    final int tabPadding = tabContainerView.getPaddingLeft() + tabContainerView.getPaddingRight();
    final int tabs = actionBar.getTabCount();
    for(int i=0 ; i < tabs ; i++){
        View tab = actionBar.getTabAt(i).getCustomView();
        TextView text1 = (TextView) tab.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        text1.setMaxWidth(screenWidth/tabs-tabPadding-1);
    }
}
```

The extra `-1` is because with exact pixels the tabs jump 1 pixel, maybe due to division accuracy, the `-1` solved that.